# Using not exported type from package

Tags: go

Here is sample library package:

```
package library

type ExportedType interface {
    GetSomeField1() string
}

func Init(field1, field2 string) *notExportedType {
    return &notExportedType{
        SomeField1: field1,
        someField2: field2,
    }
}

type notExportedType struct {
    SomeField1 string
    someField2 string
}

func (t *notExportedType) GetSomeField1() string {
    return t.SomeField1
}

func (t *notExportedType) GetSomeField2() string {
    return t.someField2
}
```

And here how I can use it:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "./library"
)

func main() {
    var record1 library.ExportedType = library.Init("record1 field1", "record1 field2")
    fmt.Println(record1.GetSomeField1())
//  fmt.Println(record1.GetSomeField2())   <- undefined (type library.ExportedType has no field or method GetSomeField2)
//  fmt.Println(record1.SomeField1)        <- undefined (type library.ExportedType has no field or method SomeField1)
//  _ = record1.(*library.notExportedType) <- cannot refer to unexported name library.notExportedType


    record2 := library.Init("record2 field1", "record2 field2")
    fmt.Println(record2.GetSomeField1())
    fmt.Println(record2.GetSomeField2())
    fmt.Println(record2.SomeField1)
//  fmt.Println(record2.someField2)         <- undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method someField2)
}
```

I export `ExportedType` interface type and `Init` function in *library*.
And I got non intuitive result with using short variable declaration:

1. Why I can achieve to method of ***not*** exported type and it's field (`record2.GetSomeField2()` and `record2.SomeField1`)?
2. Is this behaviour standard for **go** compiler or it is lucky case and can changed in different version?

I test this with `go version go1.13.4 linux/amd64`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`notExportedType` is not an unexported type, it is an unexported name. Thus, you cannot declare a new instance of that type outside the package. If you have an instance of this `notExportedType` type, you can still access the exported member fields and methods of that type. This is the standard and specified behavior. Exporting only applies to the name.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers

Comment: TinyGo does this with type pwmGroup.  vars of *pwmGroup and methods are exported from the machine package but not the type.  So you can get a value such as machine.PWM0 and assign it to a var, but you can't create a function that takes that as a parameter because the type name is not exported.  Yes this hides the inner workings of the type, but it seems to break normal programming conventions.  I now have a variable I cannot pass as a parameter that is usable.

Comment: I have gotten around the above with a local interface.